# Наличие у текущего пользователя прав администратора

Tags: c++, winapi

Пользователь запускает установщик пакета приложений. Один из компонентов пакета требует админских прав и установщик должен определить стоит ли запускать данный файл при установке или нет: если пользователь админ - запустить, если нет - пропустить файл.

Какими средствами *WinAPI* можно получить такую информацию о текущем пользователе?

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
#include "Shlobj.h"

// ...

BOOL IsAdmin = IsUserAnAdmin();
```

Не забудьте подлинковать Shell32.lib.
Вот [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Я так понимаю, что данная функция является устаревшей.

Comment: @alexolut: Это да, но если работает, зачем сложный код, когда можно простой?

Comment: Если ТС подходит, то пожалуйста. Но стоит иметь в виду, что в современных версиях ОС может и не работать должным образом.

Comment: Ох уж эта Shell32.lib - не дружит с ней MinGW. Потанцую с бубном, потом отпишусь работает или нет. Спасибо

Comment: Не удалось пока заставить работать IsUserAdmin(), нашёл вот такой [пример](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118626) - MinGW ругается на команду __leave. Это что за зверь такой? Похоже на команду ассемблера. Чем заменить в плюсах - break, continue...?

Comment: Не, это не ассемблер, это старая Майкрософтовская имплементация try/catch/finally (ещё с тех времён, когда этого не было в языке)

Comment: @Iceman: А нету Shell32.lib для MinGW? Понятно, что использовать .lib от Visual Studio с MinGW нельзя.